# strange behaviour of variable named "status" in javascript

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
var status = [true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false];
var status1 = [true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false];

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = status[2];
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = status1[2];
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vdr2r38r/

Why is the behavior different  for identical variables with different names?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you run your code in global context! `var` bound variables are bound to the function scope. If you have no function you are in global context, which means in a browser you are on the `window` object.

This code will log `Demo`:

```
<script>
  var foo = "Demo";
  console.log(window.foo);
</script>
```

---

Now your code breaks because `window.status` is [reserved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status).

An easy fix is to surround your code by a function to provide a new context for your variables, which is always good practice.

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var status = [true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false];
        var status1 = [true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false];

        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = status[2];
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = status1[2];
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The word `status` is a reserved keyword, so you need to rename it like `status3` or something else. See snippet below. You can also see a list of reserved words by visiting this link: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
var status3 = [true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false];
var status1 = [true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false];

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = status3[2];
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = status1[2];
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

change variable name 'status' , it is a Windows Reserved Word.
In HTML you must avoid using the name of HTML and Windows objects and properties

Answer (score 1):

## ES6 / ES2015 solution

Use `let` or `const` when declaring your global variables. [They do not get defined on the window object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55030498/why-dont-const-and-let-statements-get-defined-on-the-window-object). Therefore, clashes with [`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) or [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) and other properties of the global object can be avoided.

Demonstration below:

#### `let`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
let status = [true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false];
let status1 = [true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false];

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = status[2];
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = status1[2];
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

#### `const`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
const status = [true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false];
const status1 = [true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false];

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = status[2];
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = status1[2];
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

See also [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)