# why don't const and let statements get defined on the window object

Tags: javascript

Let's take the following code for example:

```js
const constVar = 'some string';
let letVar = 'some string';
var varVar = 'some string';

(function() {
  console.log(window.constVar); // prints undefined
  console.log(window.letVar); // prints undefined
  console.log(window.varVar); // prints 'some string'
})();
```

According to the description of the `const` statement by mdn:

> This declaration creates a constant whose scope can be either global or local to the block in which it is declared.

And I assume `let` works in the same way.

In this case, the "block" is contained within the global scope. I guess the important distinction here is that while `const constVar` is "globally" accessible it still doesn't define it on the `window` object.

Which leads me to think that global scope and the `window` object are disparate. Which ultimately leads to 2 questions.

1. Why do variables declared using the `var` keyword get defined on `window` and variables declared with `const` and `let` not defined on `window`?
2. What is the difference between "global scope" and the `window` object provided to us by browsers.

Comment: window also inherits from other places, like Object.prototype and elements with IDs for example. "Accidental" (intrinsic) globals were never a great idea anyway, so the newer specs clean up "slop" from prior JS implementations without breaking existing code. This is slightly outside of JS proper, being an implementation detail; eg. Node.js has no `window`.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah i guess that is the question i'm getting at, but like you said, it seems like the intended behavior was never to even let `var` define things on `window`

Comment: @AndrewKim I'm not sure you can say that about the intention behind `var` when ECMAScript version 1 explicitly defines that `var` declarations become properties of the global object [page 51 in this document or page 62 in your PDF viewer](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> 1. Why do variables declared using the `var` keyword get defined on window and variables declared with `const` and `let` not defined on window?

Because the specification says so. If you are asking for the reason behind that decision, then you should reach out to the specification maintainers.

Classes do not become properties of the global object either btw.

> 2. What is the difference between "global scope" and the `window` object provided to us by browsers.

There are two types of base [environment records](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-environment-records) according to the spec:

- Declarative Environment Record
- Object Environment Record

A *Declarative Environment Record* is basically your standard environment that you get when calling a function. All bindings (variables, constants, etc) are defined in some internal data structure that cannot be accessed from normal code.

An *Object Environment Record* on the other hand uses an actual JavaScript object to store bindings. This is used for example by the now deprecated `with` statement:

```js
with({foo: 42}) {
  console.log(foo);
}
```

Now, a [**Global Environment Record**](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-global-environment-records) actually consists of two environment records: A declarative environment record and an object environment record. The object environment is backed by the global object, i.e. `window` and contains `var` declarations and other globals that the browser provides. The declarative environment contains the `let`, `const`, `class`, etc declarations.

Comment: this makes sense(the specs rationale) If you had to venture your best guess, what would you say is that rationale they took for that differentiation between variable assignment statements with regard to how they interact or don't interact with the `window` object?

Comment: I'm not sure tbh. Having everything on a global object is not worse than putting everything into global scope. However, the global object is defined as a "host object", which means it can actually behave however the implementation wants. Maybe this made it harder to enforce `const` bindings (i.e. `const foo = 42; window.foo = 21;`).

Comment: @JonasWilms: There is always only one global scope in an environment. All `<scripts>` on a page share the same environment. Whether or not a global variable is also a property of `window` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @felix whoops, I actually thought a new one would be created for each script ... then your point about constants seems to go into a good direction ...

Comment: @JonasWilms: There is module scope for scripts loaded as modules.

Answer (score 7):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

> This declaration creates a constant whose scope can be either global or local to the block in which it is declared. 
>   **Global constants do not become properties of the window object, unlike var variables**. An initializer for a constant is required; that is, you must specify its value in the same statement in which it's declared (which makes sense, given that it can't be changed later).

To answer your 2nd question, global variable can be accessed through window object. However, there is an exception for const.

Comment: so why is `let` behaving like `const` here?

Comment: `let` and `const` are the same in term of scoping.