# At what point does a function object have properties?

Tags: javascript, function

Functions being first class objects, it seems their local data at some point must have properties, but I'm confused on when/how this happens.

Take for example:

```
var output = function(x){
    var s = "string";
    delete s;
    return s + " " + x;
};
console.log(output("bean"));
```

outputs `string bean`. I'm not sure if I expected it to delete `s` or not I was just messing around, because I thought `var` declared globally become a property of the window object.

I know `delete` doesn't work on local variables, and it only works on object properties. And because Functions are objects, I'm wondering at what point does local data in a function become a "property"

Comment: read what [the delete operator does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering at what point does local data in a function become a "property"

It doesn't. You're confusing a function *invocation* with ordinary object-like interaction with the function.

Like all objects, functions can have arbitrary key-value properties associated with them eg:

```js
var fn = function(x){
  // do something
  // not important
};
fn.foo = 'foo';
console.log(fn.foo);
```

Unless you explicitly assign a property to the function like this, the function won't have properties other than the usual ones that a function has (like `.prototype`).

Still, assigning such arbitrary properties to a function is *pretty weird*, and probably shouldn't be done in most cases.

Other properties that functions often have are `.name` (named function name), `.length` (refers to the number of arguments the function takes).

This is in contrast to non-object primitives, which cannot have key-value pairs assigned to them:

```js
'use strict';
const someStr = 'foo';
someStr.bar = 'bar';
```

(though, when you try to reference a property on a primitive, the interpreter will turn it into an object by wrapping it in the appropriate prototype first, so that prototypal inheritance works with it)

Comment: So how does global variables becoming properties of the window object work?

Comment: That's a completely different issue, but basically, it's just the way things are. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55030498/why-dont-const-and-let-statements-get-defined-on-the-window-object Note that variables declared with `const` or `let` do not get assigned to the global object, though, even if they're on the top level