# Where are constants created in a global scope stored in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Where are constants created in a global scope stored in JavaScript?

For example, if I create a variable using: `var var_example = '123'`, I can access it by `window.var_example`.

However, if I create a const variable using: `const const_example = '456'`, then how do I access it?

I need this to create an immutable/read-only global variable in a function.
I can create an ordinary global variable in a function using: `window.in_function_var = 'global variable'`, but I don’t know how to create a *constant/immutable/read-only* global variable in a function; it seems to me that this can be done by accessing a scope with constants and adding the desired variable there.

Comment: With regards to how you access a `const` variable - you do it as you normally would; by name within its scope. This seems to be an X/Y question. What is the actual issue you're trying to address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables declared using the `const` and `let` not defined on window [because the specification says so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55031001/3082296).

---

You could use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to add a property to the window object. This will set `writable: false` and `configurable: false` by default

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, "in_function_var", {
  value: 'global variable'
})

console.log(in_function_var)

in_function_var = "updated"
console.log(in_function_var)

delete window.in_function_var
console.log(in_function_var)
```

In strict mode, it throws an error if you try to update or delete the property:

```js
"use strict"

Object.defineProperty(window, "global_var", {
  value: 'global variable'
})

try {
  global_var = "updated"
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e)
}

try {
  delete window.global_var
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, both answers helped a lot. I'd like to clarify if I can somehow redefine a function variable with this method. When variable is declared using  function example_var() {} then example_var cannot be redefined by defineProperty.

Comment: @sopafoy just set the `value` to that function function: `Object.defineProperty(window, "example_var", {
  value: function example_var() { ... }
})`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to define an immutable property for **window** object.
But this is not the same as a constant. It will not be possible to change it, but there will be no same error when trying to change.

```
"use strict"
const CONST1 = 1;

function setGlobalConst() {
  Object.defineProperty(window, "CONST2", {
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: false,
      writable: false,
      value: 2
  });
};

setGlobalConst();

console.log("CONST1: " + CONST1);
console.log("CONST2: " + CONST2);

// no have error but not mutted
CONST2 = 3;
// error
CONST1 = 2;
```