# Why global let variables not added to window object of browser?

Tags: javascript, dom

Consider the code below which I am running in my chrome browser console:

```
var x = "hello";

let foo =  function(){
  console.log("hi");
};

console.log(x); // hello
console.log(foo()); //hi

console.log(window.x); // hello
console.log(window.foo()); // Error
```

If I had used `var foo =...` instead of `let foo = ..` then this would have worked. Why ?

Comment: Because that's how `let` is defined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55030498/why-dont-const-and-let-statements-get-defined-on-the-window-object

Answer (score 4):

This is by [design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

> let allows you to declare variables that are limited to a scope of a block statement, or expression on which it is used, unlike the var keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope. The other difference between var and let is that the latter is initialized to a value only when a parser evaluates it (see below).
>
> Just like const the let **does not create properties of the window**
>    object when declared globally (in the top-most scope).

Comment: From MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let