# How to get all JavaScript functions available to the webpage HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am wondering whether it is possible to get all the JavaScript functions that are included in the HTML. For example, if my HTML includes the following:

```
<script src="https://www.example.com/script.js"></script>
<script>
  function foo() {}
  function bar() {}
</script>
```

How do I use JavaScript to retrieve all the JS functions available to this webpage. In this case, I would need to retrieve `foo`, `bar` and all the functions defined in `https://www.example.com/script.js`. Doing `document.getElementsByTagName("script");` only returns the scripts as HTML objects, but I need to get all the functions for each script included in the HTML. Can this be done?

Comment: `"Can this be done?"` Yes, but it is extremely hard to do so. You'd need to get all of the script tags' innerHTML if it has no `src`, but if it does, you'd need to use `fetch()` with that url and get the text response. One you get all of that, you'd need a JS parser to find every single function declaration and modifications to `window`.

Answer (score 4):

You could iterate on the window object and detect all functions like this:

```
var list = [];
for (let i in window) {
    if (typeof(window[i]) === "function")
        list.push(i);
}
console.log(list)
```

By doing this around your script, we can detect functions that were added in-between.

```
<script>
var list1 = [];
for (let i in window) {
    if (typeof(window[i]) === "function")
        list1.push(i);
}
</script>

<script>
// The script to measure
function newFunction() {}
</script>

<script>
var list2 = [];
for (let i in window) {
    if (typeof(window[i]) === "function")
        list2.push(i);
}
let functionList = list2.filter((item) => {return list1.indexOf(item) == -1})
console.log(functionList.join(" "));
</script>
```

Comment: `window` itself is recursively defined: `window.window.window.window.window.window === window`. This also get variables, objects, arrays, etc., not just functions. Plus this also gets native functions like `alert()`.

Comment: @Samathingamajig I updated my answer according to your comment to measure between to scripts, thank you for your feedback. I also added `if (typeof(window[i]) === "function")` to filter out objects, arrays, etc.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with arrow functions https://jsfiddle.net/m27nrovh/ (has nothing to do with `bees` being a multilayer arrow function, even a normal arrow function doesnt work)

Comment: Interesting find! In your example, it does not work with `const bees...` or `let bees...`. However, if I change to `var bees...`, it works again and "bees" is detected. I suppose the `let` and `const` will be a limitation of this solution.

Comment: TIL variables declared with `const` and `let`, even when they aren't in a function, don't get added to the `window` object https://stackoverflow.com/a/55031001/12101554