# Boolean condition is always false when using `status == true`

Tags: javascript, boolean

So i just started learning javascript, I'm in the functions module now and I was playing around with it and suddenly i ran into a doubt:

why is this:

```js
if(x==true){
 return 1;
}
```

different from this:

```js
if(x){
 return 1;
}
```

?

You see, i have this code:

```js
function isAdult(age){
    if(age >= 18){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function nameAndAge(string, boolean){
    if(boolean == true){

        var my_string = string + " is adult";
        return my_string
    }
    var my_string = string + " is under age";
    return my_string

}

var talisa_age = 22;
var talisa_name = "Talisa Maegyr";

var status = isAdult(talisa_age);

var str = nameAndAge(talisa_name,status);
console.log(str)
```

and regardless of the "talisa_age" value i get the following output:

```
"Talisa Maegyr is under age"
```

however, if i chaged the nameAndAge's validation to

```js
if(boolean){
        var my_string = string + " is adult";
        return my_string
}
```

the code works as intended...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All falsey values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript) (for the question in the post body).... or: [strange behaviour of variable named “status” in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522741/strange-behaviour-of-variable-named-status-in-javascript) (for the question in the title)

Comment: Also [Can't populate array called `status`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082475/cant-populate-array-called-status)

Comment: Incidentally, you can simply the logic quite a bit viz.

`function isAdult(age) {
 return age >= 18;
}

function nameAndAge(string, boolean){
 return string+(boolean ? " is adult" : " is under age");
}`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you `console.log(typeof status)` you'll see it's a string. Why? The answer is that `status` is a special variable, [`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status), which no longer has any effect on the window status bar but is nonetheless converted back to a string (presumably for display) when assigned a value.

The standard [states](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#dom-window-status):

> For historical reasons, the `status` attribute on the [`Window`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#window) object must, on getting, return the last string it was set to, and on setting, must set itself to the new value. When the `Window` object is created, the attribute must be set to the empty string. It does not do anything else.

So, your conditional is `if ("true" == true)`<sup>*</sup>, which is false even with coercion. Changing it to `if ("true")` appears to work because nonempty strings are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

If you name your variable something else like `status_` the program behaves normally. Even better, avoid variable declarations in the global scope and/or use `const` or `let` which are preferable to `var` and can help prevent weird bugs like this.

Minimal reproduction of the problem:

```js
console.log(typeof status);
var status = 42;
console.log(typeof status);
```

A few possible fixes:

```js
var status_ = 42;
console.log(typeof status_);

const status = 42;
console.log(typeof status);

(() => {
  var status = 42;
  console.log(typeof status);
})();
```

<sup>*</sup>: Note that some browsers treat `window.status` as read-only, for example IE11. `status` would be `""` in such cases and you'll get differently unusual behavior.

---

Further reading:

- [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431)
- [Is there any reason to use the "var" keyword in ES6?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274342/)
- [Const in JavaScript: when to use it and is it necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237105/)

Comment: I was debugging this and I thought I was losing my mind. But yeah, this is why you _always_ use `const` or `let`.

Comment: @AlexWayne Same haha questions/answers like these is why I love StackOverflow.

Comment: good to know and will update all my scripts so far to use let and const instead of var.

Comment: Also avoid  global variables outside of blocks

Comment: It gets even worse than this, because if the `isAdult` function returned 1 and 0 instead of true and false, it would've worked absolutely fine because `"1" == true`...