# When the value of status is true then even the if statement is not alerting done

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, if-statement

As you can see at last I set the status to be true when sign up is done successfully but the following if statement is now working and I don't know why. I have searched it everywhere but can't find a solution that's why I have to post this question. Please somebody help me. Thanks in advance !!

```
var status = false;

function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}

$("#btn").click(function () {
  var error = "";
  var missing = "";
  var regex1 = /Email/;
  var regex2 = /Number/;

  if ($("#email").val() == "") {
    missing += "<br> Email";
  }

  if ($("#number").val() == "") {
    missing += "<br> Phone Number";
  }

  if ($("#password").val() == "") {
    missing += "<br> Password";
  }

  if ($("#passwordConfirm").val() == "") {
    missing += "<br> Confirm Password";
  }

  if (missing != "") {
    error += "Following field(s) are missing:" + missing;
  }

  if (isEmail($("#email").val()) == false && missing.match(regex1) == null) {
    error += "<p> Email address is not valid </p>";
  }

  if (
    $.isNumeric($("#number").val()) == false &&
    missing.match(regex2) == null
  ) {
    error += "<p> Phone Number is not valid </p>";
  }

  if ($("#password").val() != $("#passwordConfirm").val()) {
    error += "<p> Passwords are not matching </p>";
  }

  if (error != "") {
    $("#errorMessage").html(error);
  } else {
    $("#successMessage").show();
    $("#errorMessage").hide();
    status = true;
  }

  if (status === true) {
    alert("done");
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boolean condition is always false when using \`status == true\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62479819/boolean-condition-is-always-false-when-using-status-true)

Comment: Are you really sure the`status` gets set to true? Really no errors? Add a `console.log` or add `debugger` right before setting the status to verify.

Comment: See the working answer below. Do not forget to up-vote and accept as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code you. Just run snippet see it in action.

Reason your `status` is always `false` is that you are declaring it outside the click event. Once the you all input are validated the status = false does not know where to update to true.

Always i have added a `.show()` function to your error `.html`. Basically if all the input are good to go the `errorMessage` element will hide and if the user remove the a value from input again - The div is set to `hide()` hence why we need to show the error again on the same element.

Basically its not in the `click` event `scope`

```js
$("#btn").on('click', function() {
  var status = false;
  var error = "";
  var missing = "";

  if (!$("#email").val()) {
    missing += "<br> Email";
  }

  if ($("#number").val() == "") {
    missing += "<br> Phone Number";
  }

  if (missing != "") {
    error += "Following field(s) are missing:" + missing;
  }

  if (error != '') {
    $("#errorMessage").html(error).show();
  } else {
    $("#errorMessage").hide();
    status = true;
  }

  if (status == true) {
    alert("done");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="email" />

<input type="text" id="number" />

<button id="btn">Click Me</button>

<div id="errorMessage"></div>
```

Hope this helps.